# Redefine keyboard shortcut for edebug-defun in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

The command <kbd>C-u C-M-x</kbd> runs the `(edebug-defun)`.
I tried to redefine this shortcut as

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-d")  'edebug-defun)
```

and it did not work, so then I also tried

```
(defun my-edebug-test ()
  (interactive)
  (edebug-defun))

(local-set-key (kbd "C-d")  'my-edebug-test)
```

But it did not work either..

Comment: I've never used a `local-set-key`, and instead normally use either a `global-set-key` like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer)`, or a major-mode `define-key . . .`  like `(eval-after-load "org-agenda" '(progn (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'lawlist-org-agenda-edit) ))`

Comment: @lawlist Yes but it should work in the current buffer.. I tested this code in the same buffer.. so there was no mode changes

Comment: @lawlist I tested it now with `global-set-key` and it did not work either..

Comment: Does `edebug-defun` have `(interactive)` in it?

Comment: `(local-set-key (kbd "C-d") (lambda () (interactive) (message "Hello world.")))`

Comment: @lawlist From the libary file: `edebug.el`: it is defined as `(defalias 'edebug-defun 'edebug-eval-top-level-form)` and `edebug-eval-top-level-form` is an interactive function..

Comment: @lawlist Your last command works fine.. I get the message `"Hello world."` when pressing `C-d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `(local-set-key (kbd "C-d")  'edebug-defun)` in an `emacs -Q` session works as it should. (Namely, `C-h k C-d` returns `edebug-defun`).The problem seems to be local to your setup. Check to make sure something else isn't rebinding it afterward.

I suggest this process:

- Backup your `.emacs`
- Delete half of your `.emacs`. (From a functionality standpoint)

  - Does it work? Then the issue is in that half you deleted.

    - Revert to the original and repeat this process on only that half
  - Does it still fail? Then the issue is in that half that's left.

    - Repeat the process

After following this to completion, you will have a minimal error case, and we can help you further.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right.. I have messed up somewhere.. It works for me also with `emacs -Q`..